# center point in camera view

Tags: python, camera

Is there a simple way in python to rotate/position a camera so that a specific point (X,Y,Z) is in the middle of the camera viewfinder in Blender 2.8?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Get the camera-object direction as a vector by subtracting the cameras location from the objects location: `direction`
2. Convert this vector to a *look at* quaternion with the vectors [`to_track_quat('Z', 'Y')`](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_72b_release/mathutils.html?highlight=track_quat#mathutils.Vector.to_track_quat) function. This function returns a quaternion `rot` which points its ***Z*** in the direction of the *direction* vector and its ***Y*** in the direction of the global Y.
   Convert `rot` to a 4x4 matrix.
3. Convert the cameras location into a Translation Matrix and store it in `loc`.
4. Compose the new camera matrix by matrix-multiplying the `loc` matrix and the `rot` matrix and assign it to the camera `matrix_world`.

```
import bpy
import mathutils

cam = bpy.context.scene.camera
object = bpy.context.active_object

direction = cam.location - object.location

rot = direction.to_track_quat('Z', 'Y').to_matrix().to_4x4()
loc = mathutils.Matrix.Translation(cam.location)

cam.matrix_world =  loc @ rot
```

Comment: thanks for the explanation.  Would you be able to comment on this post:  https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/151034/blender-2-8-python-manipulating-the-camera-for-resized-objects